# Export data from Relationship betwen 3 tables with functions in single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing because I have 3 tables

1. `Customer` (id, first_name, last_name)
2. `Sales1` (id, customer_id, price, sale_date)
3. `Sales2` (id, customer_id, price, sale_date)

I need to make a query that export only 1 row by customer with number of sells, sums of sales (that two tables) and last sell date. The All these things exported between two dates.

I've tried a union, but I can't get the customer data

```
Select *
from sales1
where sale_date >= DATE(DATE_FORMAT('2001-04-1','%Y-%m-%d'))
      and sale_date <= DATE(DATE_FORMAT('2010-04-1','%Y-%m-%d'))
union
Select *
from sales2
where sale_date >= DATE(DATE_FORMAT('2001-04-1','%Y-%m-%d'))
      and sale_date <= DATE(DATE_FORMAT('2010-04-1','%Y-%m-%d'))
```

After this I've tried a inner join between sales tables but I get a table with duplicated values

```
Select * 
from customer
inner join sales1 on customer.cliente_id = sales1.cliente_id 
inner join sales2 on customer.cliente_id = sales2.cliente_id 
where (sales1.sale_date >= DATE(DATE_FORMAT('2001-04-1','%Y-%m-%d'))
       and sales1.sale_date <= DATE(DATE_FORMAT('2010-04-1','%Y-%m-%d')))
       and (sales2.sale_date >= DATE(DATE_FORMAT('2001-04-1','%Y-%m-%d'))
       and sales2.sale_date <= DATE(DATE_FORMAT('2010-04-1','%Y-%m-%d')));
```

I have two problems:

1. Write a query to get all correct data
2. Add a function in query that only export on row by customer with number of sales in two tables, sums of prices and the last sale date.

I need to export from MySQL in one single query (this is a challenge). Excuse my poor English.

Comment: What's wrong with `sale_date >= '2001-04-01'`? Beyond that, if you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is this:

```
SELECT
    sales.id,
    COUNT(sales.sales_id) AS sales_count,
    SUM(sales.sales_price) AS price_sum,
    MAX(sales.sales_date) AS last_sale
FROM
    (SELECT
        c.id,
        s1.id AS sales_id,
        s1.price AS sales_price,
        s1.sale_date AS sales_date
     FROM
        customer c
        INNER JOIN sales1 s1 ON c.id = s1.customer_id
     UNION
     SELECT
       c.id,
       s2.id AS sales_id,
       s2.price AS sales_price,
       s2.sale_date AS sales_date
     FROM
      customer c
      INNER JOIN sales2 s2 ON c.id = s2.customer_id) AS sales
WHERE
    sales.sales_date >= '2001-04-01' AND sales.sales_date <= '2010-04-01'
    AND sales.sales_date >= '2001-04-01' AND sales.sales_date <= '2010-04-01'
GROUP BY
    sales.id;
```

Comment: This solve my problem but still have one error, is the result of number os sales and the sum of sales is one more that expected.

Comment: @SchwartsHiddwnbroug I updated my query with the correct one. I guess that happens when I get 2 hrs sleep. [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3097/6) is an sql fiddle showing the result.